# List view grouped by type "Number" then by type "Text" does not expand to show entries in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, calculated-column, date-time

List view is grouped by field **"Created year"** of type *"Number"* and then by field **"Created month"** of type *"Text"* does not show entries while trying to expand the grouping. Both are calculated columns and return *Number* and *Text* respectively.

I have also tried by returning *Date* from **"Created year"** and also *Date* from **"Created month"** but it still does not let item entries expand

Column: Created year settings:
[image]

Column: Created month settings:
[image]

View group by settings:
[image]

List view does NOT expand values:
[image]

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have your issue solved?

Same issue post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d77e44f2-7af4-4329-8b21-366abce9497a/list-view-grouped-by-type-quotnumberquot-then-by-type-quottextquot-does-not-expand-to-show?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: Yea bro thats what I posted on msdn